# Weird error when compiling Common Lisp code

Tags: common-lisp, clos

I am getting the following error trying to compile some code:

> Lambda list of method #  is incompatible with that of the generic function
>   INITIALIZE-INSTANCE. Method's lambda-list : (PAT::E)
>   Generic-function's   : (CCL::INSTANCE &REST CCL::INITARGS &KEY
>                           &ALLOW-OTHER-KEYS)

Here is the code causing the error:

```
(defclass event ()
  ((timestamp
    :initarg :timestamp
    :accessor timestamp)
   (value
    :initarg :value
    :accessor value)))

(defclass update (event)
  ((security
    :initarg :sectype
    :accessor sectype)))

(defclass prc (update)
  ((lastp
    :accessor lastp)
   (lastv
    :accessor lastv)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((e prc)) ; <- :(
  (setf (lastp e) (first (value e)))
  (when (second (value e))
    (setf (lastv e) (second (value e)))))
```

Any hints as to what might be causing the error would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `&key` at the end of the argument list to your `initialize-instance` method.

To quote from "Practical Common Lisp", chapter "17. Object Reorientation: Classes":

> The `&key` in the parameter list is required to keep the method's parameter list congruent with the generic function's--the parameter list specified for the `INITIALIZE-INSTANCE` generic function includes `&key` in order to allow individual methods to supply their own keyword parameters but doesn't require any particular ones. Thus, every method must specify `&key` even if it doesn't specify any `&key` parameters.